# Local SonarScanner not importing lcov.info for react project

Tags: sonarqube

I have a react typescript project, and I am trying to do use sonar scanner to get code coverage locally. I've generated a `lcov.info` file by using `npm test --coverage`. Now, I am trying to get sonar-scanner to read the `lcov.info` file, however, I think sonar-scanner is not reading the `lcov.info` file.

in sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/__tests__/**/*, **/*.d.ts, src/serviceWorker.ts
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/__tests__/*

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=**/lcov.info
```

I have tried using     `sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=**/lcov.info` as well, but it does not solve the problem.

In the sonarscanner logs, I found this.

```
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=5ms
```

I think it might be strange that this is in the logs, given that this is not a Java project. What can I do to let sonar scanner read my lcov.info?

Answer (score 0):

The `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` property takes a comma separated list of paths. It means you cannot use `**` to search in all directories.

Example:

- file structure:

  ```
  your-project-root
    |- src
    \- build
         |-lcov1.info
         \-lcov2.info
  ```
- `sonar-project.properties`:

  ```
  sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=build/lcov1.info,build/lcov2.info
  ```